# Stress in the word /telephoning/

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

Could someone tell me how the word /telephoning/ is pronounced with the stress made clear?

Comment: The stresses fall exactly as in the words *television* and *agitated*.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: /**tel** e phon ing/.

Slightly longer answer: primary stress goes on /tel/, and there is secondary stress on /phon/.

Contextual addendum: /telephoning/ is not used in conversation, in my experience: /**phon**ing/ is used instead. (I'd give you the IPA transcription, but I'm not sure whether it would render properly here)

Comment: Thanks. I think it would if you could use an IPA keyboard and copy the symbols. You could also use rhyming words too, but I think I get it anyway.